# Esper absence of event for dynamic list

Tags: esper, complex-event-processing, nesper

I'm trying to figure out a basic scenario to determine if I should base an alerting application on Esper.

I have a set of sensors that change dynamically over time. Each of these are configured with a timeout that defines how often I should receive a Reading for the sensor. I want Esper to inform me when a Reading has not arrived in time.

Using this event pattern it seems to work, although I have no way of altering the set of sensors once Esper is started.

```
every s=Sensor -> (every (timer:interval(s.Timeout sec) and not Reading(SensorId=s.SensorId)))
```

How could I achieve this? I'm guessing that I need to change the "every s=Sensor" part into something different since events are immutable.

Comment: This is already handling any number of sensor-ids....your questions doesn't make any sense.

Comment: See this link:  http://espertech.com/esper/solution_patterns.php#absence-8

Comment: Or this one: http://espertech.com/esper/solution_patterns.php#large_number_statements